# Is this a flowering plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I just received a small plant as a gift from a friend.

[image: image of the plant]

Here is its leaf:

[image: leaf of plant]

---

I tried looking it up on [flowers of India](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/garden.html), but their database is too much to read manually.

Physical description:

It's short, around 5 inches, probably a flowering plant as per my experience (She says it is a cactus but I don't think so). The leaf is around 1.5 cm and has a cone+cylinder like structure.

Which species is this plant, and is it a flowering one?

---

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's a Crassulaceae.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks, could you please write it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, ABcDexter, but I'll decline your offer. There are too many species, not to mention hybrids and cultivars. If I just write *"this is a Crassulaceae"*, I'll get a bunch of downvotes. Let's wait more time, maybe someone identifies the species. By the way, I forgot to say: the answer to your question is **yes**, this is a flowering plant, crassulaceans are angiosperms.

Comment: Thanks again @GerardoFurtado. Could you check if this is the one [Pachyphytum viride](http://www.boldsystems.org/index.php/Taxbrowser_Taxonpage?taxid=163572)

Comment: It looks like, but this is a very complicated group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Crassula tetragona*, also known as mini pine tree (for its extreme use in bonsai technique), native to South Africa.
[image: image of the plant]

It is a succulent; a xerophyte (a kind of plant which needs very less water for survival), characterised with fleshy leaves developed due to evolution for storing water, this plant attains a height up to 3 meters.

---

Flowering in this plant usually take place in summer season, the flowers are yellowish orange and white.
[image: image of the flower]

Comment: Please edit your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references — i.e. what makes you certain this is *Crassula tetragona* rather than some other *Crassula* (or a hybrid as mentioned by @user24284). Without this a non-expert cannot evaluate whether your answer is correct. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be of the very variable species of *[Cotyledon orbiculata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotyledon_orbiculata)*. Probably the [flanaganii](http://www.crassulaceae.ch/de/artikel?akID=29&aaID=2&aiID=O&aID=1559) variation.

If that proves to be right, your plant is very much flowering. Since it is native to south africa, I don't know if you will be able to witness its flowers in your home or garden.

In any case keep domestic animals away, since to many (including dogs) this plant proved to be toxic on ingestion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this is the one.